# Element-wise minimum of multiple vectors in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I know that in numpy I can compute the element-wise minimum of two vectors with

```
numpy.minimum(v1, v2)
```

What if I have a list of vectors of equal dimension, `V = [v1, v2, v3, v4]` (but a list, not an array)? Taking `numpy.minimum(*V)` doesn't work. What's the preferred thing to do instead?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`*V` works if `V` has only 2 arrays.  `np.minimum` is a `ufunc` and takes 2 arguments.

As a `ufunc` it has a `.reduce` method, so it can apply repeated to a list inputs.

```
In [321]: np.minimum.reduce([np.arange(3), np.arange(2,-1,-1), np.ones((3,))])
Out[321]: array([ 0.,  1.,  0.])
```

I suspect the `np.min` approach is faster, but that could depend on the array and list size.

```
In [323]: np.array([np.arange(3), np.arange(2,-1,-1), np.ones((3,))]).min(axis=0)
Out[323]: array([ 0.,  1.,  0.])
```

The `ufunc` also has an `accumulate` which can show us the results of each stage of the reduction.  Here's it's not to interesting, but I could tweak the inputs to change that.

```
In [325]: np.minimum.accumulate([np.arange(3), np.arange(2,-1,-1), np.ones((3,))])
     ...: 
Out[325]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.]])
```

Answer (score 10):

Convert to NumPy array and perform [`ndarray.min`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.min.html) along the first axis -

```
np.asarray(V).min(0)
```

Or simply use [`np.amin`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.amin.html) as under the hoods, it will convert the input to an array before finding the minimum along that axis -

```
np.amin(V,axis=0)
```

Sample run -

```
In [52]: v1 = [2,5]

In [53]: v2 = [4,5]

In [54]: v3 = [4,4]

In [55]: v4 = [1,4]

In [56]: V = [v1, v2, v3, v4]

In [57]: np.asarray(V).min(0)
Out[57]: array([1, 4])

In [58]: np.amin(V,axis=0)
Out[58]: array([1, 4])
```

If you need to final output as a list, append the output with [`.tolist()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html).

Comment: `np.array(V).min(0)` works as well, and might run slightly faster than using `np.asarray()`