# Comparing computational speed of these two short codes

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, numpy

In the two versions of the code, both v1 and v2 are large vectors (length ranging from 1,000 1,000,000 with len(v1)=len(v2)). I expected **code 2** to be much master than **code 1**, but it turns out **code 1** is much faster and I do not know why. Could you please explain why **code 2** is slow? Thank you.

**Code 1:**

```
norm1=math.sqrt(np.dot(v1,v1))
norm2=math.sqrt(np.dot(v2,v2))
kern=np.dot(v1,v2)/(norm1*norm2)
```

**Code 2:**

```
kern=0
for i in range(0, len(v1)):
    kern+=min(v1[i], v2[i])
```

Comment: What version of Python do you use ?

Comment: No idea why you would expect code 2 to be faster. You might want to explain that.

Comment: python 2.6.6  thank you

Comment: @StefanPochmann  I expect numpy dot product to have some sort of for-loop inside, and Code 1 contains three such for loops. Code 2 contains a single for loop with very simple computations.

Comment: Ah, but Numpy's loops are running at compiled speed (C or Fortran), which is much faster than doing loops on the Python virtual machine. Also Numpy uses native machine arithmetic, which is much faster than doing arithmetic with Python numeric objects.

Comment: @JWO Ok, that somewhat makes sense. It's wrong, but at least explains your thinking. I think that should be in the question. Anyway, none of the "computations" in code 2 are as simple as the corresponding thing in code 1. Not even the for loop itself. If you replace `kern+=min(v1[i], v2[i])` with `pass` (i.e., doing nothing), is code 2 then not still much slower than code 1?

Comment: Would btw be good to include actual times in the question, not just say "much faster".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `np.dot()` calls also require loops through the vectors, but these loops are implemented (typically) natively / in C++. Loops implemented explicitly in python (as in your code 2) are notoriously slow in comparison to such C++-based loops.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. Is there any way I can do Code 2 in a C++ way like numpy does, without using C++?

Comment: @JWO probably something like: `np.sum(np.minimum(v1, v2))`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39277693/4098013 - Merge the two arrays into a numpy matrix and calc min along the axis

Answer (score 2):

In the first code, you are using functions from standard libraries `numpy`. These are highly optimised libraries for faster computation because implemented in C. [refer this](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.in/2015/09/going-faster-with-numpy.html)

In the second code, along with overhead of `for` loop, overhead of function call to `min(v1[i]+v2[i])` each time you iterate the loop is also added and don't forget the overhead of `range(0, len(v1))` .