# broadcast arrays to same shape, then get the minimum along one axis

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

I have 3 numpy arrays with different shapes (one not even an array but a scalar) or dimensions.

```py
arr1.shape
# (3, 3, 11)
arr2  # this is the scalar
# 1
arr3.shape
# (3, 11)
```

I want to compute the minimum along a specific axis.

I tried like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39279912/18018869):

```py
np.minimum.accumulate([arr1, np.expand_dims(arr2, axis=(0,1,2)), np.expand_dims(arr3, axis=1)])
```

Result is:

> VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested
> sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays
> with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do
> this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray. 
> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
> ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I thought that would work because it matches the [broadcasting rules](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

> Two dimensions are compatible when 
> 1. they are equal, or 
> 2. one of them is 1.

Adding, subtracting or any other mathematical operation work, so why not also the minimum function?

```py
# adding works as a proof that broadcasting works
arr1 + np.expand_dims(arr2, axis=(0,1,2)) + np.expand_dims(arr3, axis=1)
```

The way I achieve what I want is the following, but it does not feel like it is the correct numpy approach. Why do I have to "manually" broadcast the arrays to same shape, when I do not need to do it with the "usual" mathematical operations like adding and subtracting. Am I missing something or is this already the most "clean" way of doing it?

```py
np.array(np.broadcast_arrays(arr1, np.expand_dims(arr2, axis=(0,1,2)), np.expand_dims(arr3, axis=1))).min(axis=0)
```

I want to add that I know about `np.minimum()`. But it only allows "comparison" of two arrays. I want to pass multiple arrays.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you mean *I want to compute the minimum along a specific axis.*? Can you show what result you're expecting?

Comment: You have only 3 arrays, better do `np.minimum(np.minimum(a1,a2), a3[:,None])`.

Comment: First make sure this works: `np.array([arr1, np.expand_dims(arr2, axis=(0,1,2)), np.expand_dims(arr3, axis=1)])`.  I suspect that's what's producing the `ragged` warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.minimum.accumulate` (or any ufunc accumulate) first makes an array from the input list. That's what gives the ragged array warning

Adding `object` dtype as required, the result is a 3 element array, with element arrays that vary in shape:

```
In [92]: np.array([arr1, np.expand_dims(arr2, axis=(0,1,2)), np.expand_dims(arr3, axis=1)],object)
Out[92]: 
array([array([[[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
               [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
               [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]],

              [[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
               [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
               [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]],

              [[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
               [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
               [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]]]),
       array([[[1]]]),
       array([[[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],

              [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],

              [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]])],
      dtype=object)
```

`np.add` can work of this 3 element array:

```
In [104]: np.add.reduce(_92).shape
Out[104]: (3, 3, 11)
In [105]: np.add.accumulate(_92).shape
Out[105]: (3,)
```

`minumum`, reduce or accumulate, give this ambiguity error:

```
In [106]: np.minimum.reduce(_92).shape
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[106], line 1
----> 1 np.minimum.reduce(_92).shape

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

That means it's comparing two arrays, and getting a boolean array.

`np.minimum(_92[0],_92[1])` works, but `np.minimum.reduce(_92[0,1])` gives this error.  It's almost as though it's doing some sort of `if` or `or/and` on the pairs; but that's hidden in compiled code.

With the `broadcast_arrays` you make a 4d array, allowing the normal `min` on an axis:

```
In [117]: np.array(np.broadcast_arrays(arr1, np.expand_dims(arr2, axis=(0,1,2)), np.expand_dims(arr3, axis=1))).shape
Out[117]: (3, 3, 3, 11)
```